# Steady-state response in matlab

Tags: matlab

We have to calculate the steady state response of the state space `A` in my code. The MATLAB function `tf(sys)` gives me the transfer functions. Now I want to multiply these `tf` functions with a step input `0.0175/s`. Next, I have to take the limit `s->0`, which will give me the steady-state response. However, I'm not sure how I would  program this in MATLAB. I have no idea how to deal with the outputs of the `tf(sys)` command. Could anyone provide some insight?  The code I wrote is below:

```
A=[ 0.00501 0.00464 -72.90 -31.34;
    -0.08570 -0.545 309 -7.4;
    0.00185 -0.00767 -0.395 0.00132;
    0 0 1 0];

B=[5.63 -23.8 -4.51576 0]'; 

C=[1 0 0 0;
    0 1 0 0;
    0 0 1 0;
    0 0 0 1];

D=0;

sys=ss(A,B,C,D);

tf=tf(sys)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to use is the [`dcgain`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dcgain.html) function to infer what the steady-state value is for each of the input/output relationships in your state-space model once converted to their equivalent transfer functions.  The DC gain is essentially taking the limit as `s->0` when calculating the step response.  However, though it's not really required to plot the step response, it may be useful to verify graphically that `dcgain` is giving you the right results.  In this case, use [`step`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/step.html). It finds the step response of linear dynamical systems, including a state-space model.  In your case, once you convert to a `tf` object, you would have to scale your transfer function by 0.0175, then invoke `step`, as well as `dcgain`.

I also renamed your last variable to `T` because `tf` is an actual function, yet you'll be overshadowing the function with the variable `tf`.

Simply put:

```
%// Your code
clear all; clc;

A=[ 0.00501 0.00464 -72.90 -31.34;
    -0.08570 -0.545 309 -7.4;
    0.00185 -0.00767 -0.395 0.00132;
    0 0 1 0];

B=[5.63 -23.8 -4.51576 0]'; %'

C=[1 0 0 0;
    0 1 0 0;
    0 0 1 0;
    0 0 0 1];

D=0;

sys=ss(A,B,C,D);    
T=0.0175*tf(sys); %// Change

%// New - find the step response
[y,t] = step(T);

%// Plot the step response
plot(t, y);
legend('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4');

%// Determine the steady-state values
format long g;
ss_values = dcgain(T);
disp(ss_values);
```

---

I get these for my steady-state values:

```
>> ss_values

ss_values =

          23.7245028635498
         -4.57981861496758
                         0
       0.00625827699339293
```

I also get this plot:

[image]

The steady-state values more or less line up with what we see in the plot.

Comment: Thank you! This helps me a lot :)

Comment: @JurriënPlijter graag gedaan. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to state why you multiply the inputs by `0.0175` and not `0.0175/s` particularly when using `dcgain` (`step` is self-explanatory).

Comment: @IKavanagh great idea. I will when I have the chance. For the OP, there isn't a need to multiply by 1/s because the `dcgain` function takes care of that.

Comment: @rayryeng That's not the reason why there isn't a need to multiply by `1/s`. All `dcgain` does is set `s = 0` and evaluate the result. It doesn't multiply by `1/s`. You can verify this with `evalfr(T, 0)` which will return the same as `dcgain(T)`. `evalfr` evaluates the frequency response for a specific frequency only, no fancy multiplication or anything additional added. The reason multiplication by `1/s` isn't needed **in this case** when using `dcgain` is because of the `s` in the Final Value Theorem which cancels with the `1/s` from the step input.

Comment: @IKavanagh I'm aware of the Final Value Theorem.  Just haven't gotten around to putting it in my answer.  The multiplication of `s` cancels with the `1/s` in the FVT which is why you can simply take the DC gain of the system.  I'm lazy, so if you want, you can edit my answer because I haven't found the time.  Cheers.